# pandas series exact match with a list of lists

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of the form :

```
      ID   |   COL
       1        A   
       1        B
       1        C
       1        D 
       2        A
       2        C
       2        D
       3        A
       3        B
       3        C
```

I also have a list of list containing sequences,for example `seq = [[A,B,C],[A,C,D]]`.

I am trying to count the number of IDs in the dataframe where in `COL`  matchs exactly an entry in `seq`. I am currently doing it the following way :-

`df.groupby('ID')['COL'].apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop = True).equals(pd.Series(vs))).reset_index()['COL'].count()`

iterating over `vs`,where `vs` is a list from `seq`.

Expected Output :-

```
  ID | is_in_seq   
   1    0 
   2    1
   3    1
```

Since the sequence in `COL` for `ID` 1 is ABCD, which is not a sequence in `seq`, the value against it is 0.

Questions:-

1.) Is there a vectorized way of doing this operation? The approach I've outlined above takes a lot of time even for a single entry from `seq`, seeing that there can be upto 30 - 40 values in col per ID and maintaining the order in `COL` is critical.

Comment: For example, I want to count ID 1 if the sequence ABCD matches either the first sequence in seq, or the second, or the third etc.

Comment: It has to be an exact match.

Comment: can you expand the input and the sequence list and also provide an expected output please (for more clarity)

Comment: Are sequences in `seq` always of length `3`?

Comment: No. The sequences  in seq can be of any length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:
You will only ever produce a zero or a one.  Because you'll be checking if the group as a whole (and there is only one whole) is in `seq`.  If `seq` is unique (I'm assuming it is) then you'll only ever have the group in `seq` or not.

First step is to make `seq` a `set` of `tuples`

```
seq = set(map(tuple, seq))
```

Second step is to produces an aggregated pandas object that contains tuples

```
tups = df.groupby('ID')['COL'].agg(tuple)
tups

ID
1    (A, B, C, D)
2       (A, C, D)
3       (A, B, C)
Name: COL, dtype: object
```

Step three, we can use `isin`

```
tups.isin(seq).astype(int).reset_index(name='is_in_seq')

   ID  is_in_seq
0   1          0
1   2          1
2   3          1
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) 
to get a string with the complete sequence. Then use `map` and `''.join` with [`DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check matches

```
new_df = (df.groupby('ID')['COL']
            .sum()
            .isin(map(''.join, seq)) 
           #.isin(list(map(''.join, seq))) #if neccesary list
            .astype(int)
            .reset_index(name = 'is_in_seq')
         )

print(new_df)
   ID  is_in_seq
0   1          0
1   2          1
2   3          1
```

**Detail**

```
df.groupby('ID')['COL'].sum()
ID
1    ABCD
2     ACD
3     ABC
Name: COL, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I timed the results of this approach, but it still took too long to come up with the numbers.